# mkdirs() not creating any folder with Xubuntu

Tags: java, ubuntu, io, mkdir

I am trying to put a file in the directory `(The system property user.home)/.plantgrower/logs`. The folder `.myprogram` does not exist, I want to create it with its sub-folders.  Here is my code :

```
File f = new File(System.getProperty("user.home") + File.pathSeparatorChar + ".plantgrower" + File.pathSeparatorChar + "logs");
System.out.println(f.mkdirs());
```

However, the output is `false` and the folder is not created. I do not understand why it did that.

Another weird thing : I have set the permissions of `user.home` (in my case `/home/matthieu`) for writing and reading for everybody, but `f.canWrite()` outputs `false`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want `File.separatorChar` not `File.pathSeparatorChar`.

`File.separatorChar` (/) is used to separate path components, such as:

```
/Users/myuser/folder1
```

`File.pathSeparatorChar` (:) is used to separate multiple paths, such as:

```
/Users/myuser/folder1:/Users/myuser/folder2
```

The actual characters are OS dependent.